# Installing Python 2.6 and Python-devel on Scientific Linux 5 (Redhat 5)?

Tags: python, linux

I have to use Scientific Linux 5.8 32-bit (long story short for some hardware compatibility issue). However, SL-5.8 comes with python 2.4 and I need python 2.5 or newer.

First I did 
      yum install gcc

Then I installed python 2.6:
      ./configure then
      make install

Then when I try to run
      yum install python-devel

I get the following:
Package python-devel-2.4.3-46.el5_8.2.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

A lot of this is newer to me, so if anyone has any help preferably the easiest to execute solutions would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If you installed python from source via `configure; make; make install`, then there should be no need to install a python-devel package.

Comment: i just downloaded the .tgz file, extracted the file, then ran "./configure" then make install i am not quite sure how to install things from source

Comment: Usually the sequence is `./configure; make; sudo make install` (I'm assuming you have admin power on your machine)?

Comment: i just downloaded the .tgz file, extracted the file, then ran "./configure" then make install, i now keep getting errors when trying to install pyvisa. when i installed sl6.2 which came with python 2.6 it worked fine. and installing pyvisa on sl5.8 with 2.4 worked fine as well. i need sl5.8 with a newer version of python however

Comment: yeah im currently logged in as root

Comment: So, in a terminal, if you type `python2.6` does it work?

Comment: yeah i can run python and when i type python -V it tells me that im running 2.6.8 however it yum install python-devel says i have 2.4 an that there is nothing to do

Comment: Ok, so you have python2.6.8 -- since you installed from source, you should have all the headers, etc. needed to build packages against it (i.e. you shouldn't need `python-devel` because you already have it).  Now what is your problem?  You can't build some 3rd party package?

Comment: yeah. also since it is built from source (and if i assume correctly that means i have the correct components) should running yum install python-devel return that i already have the one for 2.6 instead of 2.4?

Comment: `yum` is checking against it's repository for the newest version that it knows about.  Since you're using an old version of RedHat, the newest packages that your repository knows about are for python2.4 (as far as your repo is concerned, python2.6 doesn't exist yet).  However, with most things python, you usually just do `<sudo> python setup.py install` to install a package.  if `python` doesn't point to `python2.6` you may need `<sudo> python2.6 setup.py install` or something like that...

Comment: that was how i was trying to install pyvisa, however it keeps telling me that the file could not be opened successfully. I am fairly certain it is not an issue with pyvisa as I was just able to install it on another two other computers (Sl6.2 which came with python 2.6 and another computer with sl5.8 which came with python2.4)

Comment: when i did python2.4 setup.py install i was able to install pyvisa but not when i use python26

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that's the best way to do it.

You can install python 2.6 using

```
# yum install python26
```

and then the devel headers with

```
# yum install python26-devel
```

I'm not sure if these are in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) or the base distribution - if you need more detail on how to add the EPEL repo, I can explain further.

Comment: I am pretty new to linux, but neither of those commands worked so i am assuming base distribution. how may i ad the EPEL repo?

Comment: Go to [this page](http://mirror.bytemark.co.uk/fedora/epel/5/i386/repoview/epel-release.html) and download the rpm.  Then install with `rpm -i epel-release-5-4.noarch`.  Then try again...

Comment: I don't think python 2.7 is packaged for SL5.

Comment: it seems the installation is still not working, when i try to run import visa in python it tells me no module named pyvisa.visa even though i ran "python26 setup.py install" in the pyvisa directory to install it

Comment: I just had a look.  I don't have the visa binary, but if I type `python` (i.e. 2.4) then `import visa` I get `ImportError: No module named pyvisa.visa`, but if I type `python26` then `import visa` I get `OSError: /usr/local/vxipnp/linux/bin/libvisa.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`, which looks like it might work if I did have the binary.